# Building a dynamic framework without linking its dependent frameworks

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am building a dynamic framework to use across several apps. Some classes call code that is found in other third party frameworks (think Facebook, Firebase). My app will also call code in these frameworks.

Everything I read about dynamic frameworks suggests that; including the dependent frameworks is bad practice, and, linking to dependent frameworks is done at runtime (not compile time).

My plan then was to import the headers of the required frameworks but not actually link against them. I was going to link all the required frameworks in my app. When I go to build my app and my custom framework, the framework will not link because of undefined symbols.

Doesn't this contradict the theory of runtime linking? How do I get my framework to build successfully without bringing all its dependent frameworks along with it?

Answer (score 0):

You should place the third party headers in the project that makes use of them. If your framework is built as a dependency, and it makes use of those headers via briefing method, etc. then they should be added to the framework project and the frameworks themselves should be linked to the main project and simply adjust your search paths in the framework. This way it will search for libraries and frameworks where you want it too. If the framework doesn't make use of those headers then they should not be added to it.

**Edit--**
As the image shows, the frameworks are linked to the main project, and simply specify in the search paths for the dependency framework where it should look for those frameworks. Obviously assume the frameworks are the third party frameworks you are talking about.

[image]

Comment: I believe I have done that... See this screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18070771/Screen%20Shot%202016-07-14%20at%201.35.01%20PM.png